# unable to compare integer variable containing ASCII value by getchar() with '\t','\';

Tags: c

I am writing a code in c language, with custom input. And having problems to compare an int variable with '\','\t'(generally escape sequences). Here integer variable stores the ASCII value of characters. And is acquired by `getchar()`.

I have tried to change compiler,and also tried to do this with `scanf()` and storing value on another level. But for every process the take '\' as a different character and 't' as a different. And cant even compare '\'. Showing missing terminating character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c=='\')
            printf('x');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print x if `c=='\'`. the real code is a bit too long. I am sure no error in the other parts but unable to get this. every code I saw online is working. But not with mine.

Comment: To compare against the \ character, simply use the escape sequence `'\\'`. As demonstrated in the beginner-level C book, chapter strings.

Comment: `\t` does not result in an escape sequence but the tab character.

Comment: Side-note (addressed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56260141/364696)): `printf` takes string literals for the format string, not character literals. Even if you managed to compile this by fixing the '\' literal and you suppressed all the warnings from your compiler for passing `'x'`, it would almost certainly segfault (or almost worse, silently print random memory based on whatever stack garbage is added to `'x'`). You want `printf("x");`, not `printf('x');`.

Comment: thank you very much.Your time and knowledge is very much appreciated.thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is the escape character, you need to use a double-backslash to make a character literal containing a single backslash:

```
if (c=='\\')
```

Without the extra backslash, the single backslash escapes the closing single quote, so the character literal doesn't end, and the code will not compile (on the rare occasions it does, it's likely compiling garbage).

As for `\t`, if you want to compare to an actual tab, `if (c=='\t')` works just fine. But if you want to recognize a literal backslash followed by a `t`, you'll need to recognize it in two pieces, first the backslash, then read another character to see the `t`, e.g.:

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\\') {
            printf("Found escape beginning\n");
            if ((c = getchar()) == EOF) break;
            if (c == 't')
                printf("Found backslashed 't'\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Your `printf` was also wrong, as it passed a character literal to `printf`, not a string literal. I've fixed it in the expanded code above; your original code would change `printf('x');` to `printf("x");`

Comment: thanks again .brother.i have tried comparing differently but just because i was unable to compare'\' i was stuck.just opened account now.and such  great people.within minutes  help arrived..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Within a string or character constant, the `\` character acts as escape character to give the following character special meaning.  In your case, the `\` is escaping the closing `'` character meaning that the quoted character constant is not closed.

The escape sequence for a literal `\` is `\\`.  So what you want is:

```
if(c=='\\')
```